# How can I mount a subfolder of a shared folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm using this command to mount a shared folder inside my VM:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf vm_shared ~/shared/
```

Is it possible to mount a **subfolder** inside vm_shared to ~/shared/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either (additionally) export that subdirectory in VirtualBox and mount it the same way, or mount the main folder to a temporary mount point and use a bind mount to mount the subdirectory to the actual place:

```
mount -t vboxsf vm_shared /mnt
mount --bind /mnt/subdir ~/shared/
```

Answer (score -1):

Or, instead of `mount --bind...`, try this :

```
ln -s /mnt/subdir ~/shared/
```